# $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[ \left( \int_{0}^{1} e^{nx(1-x)} \ dx \right)^\frac{1}{n} + \left( \int_{0}^{1} e^{\frac{x(1-x)}{n}} \ dx \right)^{n}\right]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

To evaluate
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[ \left( \int_{0}^{1} e^{nx(1-x)} \ dx \right)^\frac{1}{n} + \left( \int_{0}^{1} e^{\frac{x(1-x)}{n}} \ dx \right)^{n}\right]$$

I have used the M.V.T to give an upper bound $2e^\frac{1}{4}$ and a lower bound $2$ for the answer, but I am not able to get the correct answer. I feel that it is associated with L'Hopital's rule and the dominated convergence theorem, but these theorems may not lead to the right way.

Comment: *Mathematica*:  $$\sqrt[6]{e}+\sqrt[4]{e}$$

Comment: For the first term use the fact that $\|f\|_n \to \|f\|_{\infty}$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: For the second term, use the fact that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\int_{X}e^{f(x)/n}\,\mu(\mathrm{d}x)\right)^n=\exp\left(\int_X f(x)\,\mu(\mathrm{d}x)\right)$$ for any probability measure $\mu$ on $X$ and suitably nice function $f$ on $X$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Where can I find this theorem and proof?

Comment: When $f$ is bounded, the proof is fairly straightforward using the inequality $$\left|e^x - 1 - x\right|\leq\frac{1}{2}|x|^2e^{|x|}.$$ Indeed, this gives $$\int_{X}e^{f(x)/n}\,\mu(\mathrm{d}x)=1+\frac{1}{n}\int_{X}f(x)\,\mu(\mathrm{d}x)+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right),$$ which then easily leads to the desired limit.

Comment: @geetha290krm Where can I find this theorem and proof? I didn't find out this theorem in Rudin and G. Bartle.

Comment: It has been asked and answered many many times on this site. In an exrecise in the chapter on $L^{p}$ spaces Rudin's gives the limit for $\|f\|_p$ as $ p \to \infty$ as well as the limit as $p \to 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For the first term**:

Using $x(1-x) \le 1/4$ on $[0, 1]$, we have $$
 \int_0^1 \mathrm{e}^{nx(1-x)}\,\mathrm{d} x \le \int_0^1 \mathrm{e}^{n/4}\,\mathrm{d} x
 = \mathrm{e}^{n/4}.
$$

Using $x(1 - x) \ge 1/4 - 1/n^2$ on $[1/2 - 1/n, 1/2 + 1/n]$ ($n > 2$), we have
$$\int_0^1 \mathrm{e}^{nx(1-x)}\,\mathrm{d} x
\ge \int_{1/2-1/n}^{1/2 + 1/n} \mathrm{e}^{nx(1-x)}\,\mathrm{d} x
\ge \int_{1/2-1/n}^{1/2 + 1/n} \mathrm{e}^{n(1/4 - 1/n^2)}\,\mathrm{d} x
= \frac{2}{n} \mathrm{e}^{n(1/4 - 1/n^2)}.$$

Thus, we have
$$\frac{2^{1/n}}{n^{1/n}}\mathrm{e}^{1/4 - 1/n^2} \le \left(\int_0^1 \mathrm{e}^{nx(1-x)}\,\mathrm{d} x\right)^{1/n} \le \mathrm{e}^{1/4}.$$

By the squeeze theorem, we have
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\int_0^1 \mathrm{e}^{nx(1-x)}\,\mathrm{d} x\right)^{1/n} = \mathrm{e}^{1/4}.$$

**For the second term**:

Using
$1 + u \le \mathrm{e}^u \le 1 + u + u^2$ on $[0, 1]$, we have
$$1 + x(1-x)/n \le \mathrm{e}^{x(1-x)/n} \le 1 + x(1-x)/n + x^2(1-x)^2/n^2.$$

Thus, we have
$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{6n} \right)^n\le \left(\int_0^1 \mathrm{e}^{x(1-x)/n}\,\mathrm{d} x \right)^n\le \left(1 + \frac{1}{6n} + \frac{1}{30n^2}\right)^n.$$

By the squeeze theorem, we have
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\int_0^1 \mathrm{e}^{x(1-x)/n}\,\mathrm{d} x\right)^n = \mathrm{e}^{1/6}.$$

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. The explanation is simple enough and adequate. Thanks!

Comment: @林國陽 You are welcome.